# How to Get value of $scope.foo in a controller from a html file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a custom html tag :

`<custom-scan id="fingscan" client="12345678" tries="3"></custom-scan>`

However client should not be a constant value, but a variable from a search result on a previous part of the workflow.

The controller has a value called `$scope.userInfo.cu` that holds the value I need to set.

hence :

```
<custom-scan id="fingscan" client="" tries="3"></custom-scan>
    <script>
        const fingscan = document.querySelector('custom-scan');
        fingscan.setAttribute("client", $scope.userInfo.cu);
        console.log(fingscan.getAttribute("client"));
    </script>
```

throws me a `ReferenceError: $scope is not defined.`, and  changing the variable to just `userInfo.cu` throws me the same, except saying userInfo is not defined.

What am I doing wrong here? my guess is the js controller and the script in the HTML file are not visible to each other. 
Please update me on how do I fix this?

Comment: `$scope` is not a global variable but something within an angular module or controller - you need to change that variable within angulars scope - https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/angularjs/angularjs-scope

Comment: I don't need to change the variable value, but assign that value to the client attribute of custom-scan

Answer (score 0):

you need to change it within angularsjs scope

```
<script>
    var ngApp = angular.module('myNgApp', []);

    ngApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
        const fingscan = document.querySelector('custom-scan');
        fingscan.setAttribute("client", $scope.userInfo.cu);
        console.log(fingscan.getAttribute("client"));        
    });
</script>
```

you may need to call `$scope.apply()` as well

Comment: I don't need to change the value of the variable, i need to get it from the controller and assign it to the client attribute of <custom-scan>.

Comment: no where am i changing anything - i am assigning the value to your custom element that you described. Even to view value of a variable you still need to be in angular scope. You are not familiar with js or angular - review both thoroughly